# Querying an Array in Graphql

Tags: sql, graphql

I have the following query on graphql

```
query articles {
  articles {
    news_link
    article_details {
      description
      title
      brands {
        name
      }
      featured_image {
        url
        }
      published_at
    }   
  }
}
```

Which will give me the following sample response

```
{
  "data": {
    "articles": [
      {
        "news_link": "http://loanstreet.com.my",
        "article_details": [
          {
            "description": "My first article",
            "title": "First Article",
            "brands": [
              {
                "name": "Fendi"
              }
            ],
            "featured_image": {
              "url": "/uploads/e5c00dbd3a3648dd8c0e1c2a44f50c0d.png"
            },
            "published_at": "2020-03-31T04:00:00.000Z"
          },
          {
            "description": "Lighter ff article",
            "title": "First Article LP",
            "brands": [
              {
                "name": "Lighter"
              }
            ],
            "featured_image": {
              "url": "/uploads/ac6c5f26050f46eebd37fa7319ab531b.png"
            },
            "published_at": "2020-03-31T04:00:00.000Z"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am trying to query and only get the response where brand name is "Fendi" but cannot seem to get it right using Graphql playground.

I tried this

```
query articles {
  articles {
    news_link
    article_details {
      description
      title
      brands(where: {name: "Fendi"}) {
        name
      }
      featured_image {
        url
        }
      published_at
    }   
  }
}
```

but it gave me this response which is not really what i want

```
{
  "data": {
    "articles": [
      {
        "news_link": "http://loanstreet.com.my",
        "article_details": [
          {
            "description": "My first article",
            "title": "First Article",
            "brands": [
              {
                "name": "Fendi"
              }
            ],
            "featured_image": {
              "url": "/uploads/e5c00dbd3a3648dd8c0e1c2a44f50c0d.png"
            },
            "published_at": "2020-03-31T04:00:00.000Z"
          },
          {
            "description": "Lighter ff article",
            "title": "First Article LP",
            "brands": [],
            "featured_image": {
              "url": "/uploads/ac6c5f26050f46eebd37fa7319ab531b.png"
            },
            "published_at": "2020-03-31T04:00:00.000Z"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am expecting a response like this

```
{
  "data": {
    "articles": [
      {
        "news_link": "http://loanstreet.com.my",
        "article_details": [
          {
            "description": "My first article",
            "title": "First Article",
            "brands": [
              {
                "name": "Fendi"
              }
            ],
            "featured_image": {
              "url": "/uploads/e5c00dbd3a3648dd8c0e1c2a44f50c0d.png"
            },
            "published_at": "2020-03-31T04:00:00.000Z"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: GraphQL has no built-in filtering. This question is specific to whatever schema you're querying. You can view the arguments available on `articles` in Playground and see if there are any that meet your requirements. Otherwise, it's not possible.

Comment: Where would i be able to see the arguments available? @DanielRearden

Comment: You can use Playground's autocomplete functionality (press ctrl+space to see available fields, arguments, etc. whereever your cursor is). You can also click the "docs" link to bring up a searchable view of the schema.